# How to decode ��! to UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, utf8-decode

Having some issues inserting data into my UTF-8 database. The main issues I'm having is with words containing ��!.

The code I'm using so far is

```
        $enc = mb_detect_encoding($content);
        $data = mb_convert_encoding($content, "ASCII", $enc);
```

But no luck so far. Does that mean it can't detect the encoding? or something else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 0):

You are converting to ASCII.  ASCII probably doesn't have the characters you need, and why would you convert to ASCII if your database supports UTF8? why not:

```
$enc = mb_detect_encoding($content);
$data = mb_convert_encoding($content, "UTF-8", $enc);
```

Comment: Even better, why convert at all? Have your web page be UTF-8, and your database be UTF-8, and never have any strings that aren't UTF-8. Presto, no conversions needed.

Comment: i agree. I don't know where this "$content" is coming from.